# input a string and compare each word with a given word using NLP Python

Tags: python, nlp

I want to input a string, tokenize it, and compare each word with a specific word (in this code, the word is 'play'). I have the code

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

txt = "bat ball cocaine golf football cake leg hand me you her she he dog cat drug"

x = word_tokenize(txt)
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 


for i in range (10):
    syn = wordnet.synsets(x[i])[0]
    print ("Synset name :  ", syn.name())

    w1 = wordnet.synset('play.n.01') 
    w2 = wordnet.synset(syn) 
    print(w1.wup_similarity(w2)) 
i = i +1
```

This gives an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-a30645977ba6> in <module>()
     13 
     14     w1 = wordnet.synset('play.n.01')
---> 15     w2 = wordnet.synset(syn) 
     16     print(w1.wup_similarity(w2))
     17 i = i +1
```

help

Comment: What is the `i = i +1` for? Also, all imports should be at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the wrong argument to the function.

Instead, you should've passed `syn.name()`

Use this `w2 = wordnet.synset(syn.name())`

With this correction, `IndexError: list index out of range` raises on 10th iteration.

Try this to solve the problem

```
syn = wordnet.synsets(x[i])
if syn:
    syn = syn[0]
else:
    continue
```

Comment: yes it works. however, yeah, there is this issue that it stops after 10th iteration. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @KhabbabZakaria `wordnet.synsets('her')` is empty, so taking first element gives an error. I edited the answer